# Java : How to sort values of a HashMap with generic Key and Value?

Tags: java, generics, comparator, comparable

I have a TreeMap that i need to Sort-By-Values. I am able sort the Map if the values are Integer type.

```
public class MapSorting {

    public static Map<String, Integer> sortByValues(Map<String, Integer> tempMap) {

        ValueComparator bvc = new ValueComparator(tempMap);
        Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(bvc);
        sortedMap.putAll(tempMap);
        return sortedMap;

    }
}


class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> {

        Map<String, Integer> base;

        public ValueComparator(Map<String, Integer> base) {
            this.base = base;
        }

        public int compare(String a, String b) {
            if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

But how do i make the method generic?? I want to be able to send Map with Key and Value of any type to this method.

I want to return a TreeMap that is sorted based on values.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: you could use , `instanceOf` or `getClass()` to get the type of object and do different comparisons in your `compare(Object, Object)` method.. But why would you want to do this?.  *Generics* was introduced to prevent errors arising from such usage. If you are thinking of breaking generics, I believe there is a flaw in your design.

Comment: You must make `compare` generic. But why do you want to make key and value generic? What is the usecase?

Comment: A TreeMap is intended to be sorted by key but you want to sort it by value. I think that the TreeMap does not fit your need. For example, you could convert your `TreeMap<String, Integer>` into a `List<Entry<Integer, String>>` and it would be far easier to sort.

Comment: @TheLostMind I would like to make the method sortByValues generic so that it can be called for any type of Map Object, i.e., Map<String,String> or Map<String,Integer> or Map<Integer,Integer>.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle The code is working fine if the Map Values are Integers. I need help to make the method work if the Map Values are String type also. Hence i need a generic way to do it that works for all types of keys and values.

Comment: @sharathgm It works but is not a good solution (IMHO). Generally, something which gets complicated is a clue that there is a design problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note** : A `TreeMap` is intended to be sorted by key, not by value. That makes me think that you should use another data structure to store your result : e.g. `List<Entry<K, V>>`.

**Note** : I highly discourage to use this piece of code because I think it is an anti-pattern. I did it only to show how it would be possible.

That said, I made it like this (need at least Java 8 or adapt the code) :

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable> Map<K, V> sortByValues(Map<K, V> tempMap) {
  TreeMap<K, V> map = new TreeMap<>(buildComparator(tempMap));
  map.putAll(tempMap);
  return map;
}

public static <K, V extends Comparable> Comparator<? super K> buildComparator(final Map<K, V> tempMap) {
  return (o1, o2) -> tempMap.get(o1).compareTo(tempMap.get(o2));
}
```

Test :

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, "B");
map.put(2, "C");
map.put(3, "A");

for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : sortByValues(map).entrySet()) {
  System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+ entry.getValue());
}
```

Output :

```
3 : A
1 : B
2 : C
```

**Note** : I dit not handle null cases because it is not important for this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a comparator that compares values that are [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

```
class ValueComparator<Comparable> implements Comparator<Comparable> {

    Map<String, Comparable> base;

    public ValueComparator(Map<String, Comparable> base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public int compare(Comparable a, Comparable b) {
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
}
```